# How to manually trigger "Scroll to top" for active scrollview component on iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uistatusbar

I know how to manually scroll a `UITableView`or `UIScrollView` to top.

I am trying to replicate the behaviour of tapping the `UIStatusBar` which automatically **finds** the active view that can be scrolled to top and scrolls it to top.

So, I want to do the same, without knowing which `UIScrollView` subclass is currently active and can be scrolled to top.

Is there a public `NSNotification` for this, or any other public method?

Answer (score 0):

`[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];`

**Update** You should traverse view hierarchy or responder chain and the first item of class `UIScrollView` that responds with `YES` to `scrollsToTop` (or if delegate implements `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:` and returns `YES`) will be your candidate for automatic scrolling

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I have noted in my question. I aldready know how to scroll a "specific" scrollview. I am trying to mimic the behaviour of tapping to Status Bar. I have to do this without specifically callinga known scrollview.

Comment: oh sorry, missed that, fixed my answer.